# Errors wih my call to context in .Net Core with missing reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, linq-to-entities

I can't seem to understand why I have errors with my method at the very bottom.

I have these two methods below that work fine.

```
    public async Task<Claim> GetClaim(string id)
    {
        var query = _context.Claims.AsQueryable();
        var claim = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.ClaimNumber == id);
        return claim;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Message>> GetMessageThread(int userId, int recipientId)
    {
        var messages = await _context.Messages
            .Include(u => u.Sender).ThenInclude(p => p.Photos)
            .Include(u => u.Recipient).ThenInclude(p => p.Photos)
            .Where(m => m.RecipientId == userId && m.RecipientDeleted == false 
                && m.SenderId == recipientId 
                || m.RecipientId == recipientId && m.SenderId == userId 
                && m.SenderDeleted == false)
            .OrderByDescending(m => m.MessageSent)
            .ToListAsync();

        return messages;
    }
```

But with this method I get two red errors under the first line and last for

> 'DbSet' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'DbSet' could be found

and

> Task> results
>   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit conversion exists

Here is the method

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetClaims(GetClaimsDto claimParams)
    {
        var claims = await _context.Claims;

        if (claimParams.MatterNumber != null) {
            claims = claims.Where(c => c.MatterNumber == claimParams.MatterNumber);
        }

        if (claimParams.FirstName != String.Empty) {
            claims = claims.Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.FirstName, "%" + claimParams.FirstName + "%"));
        }

        if (claimParams.LastName != String.Empty) {
            claims = claims.Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.LastName, "%" + claimParams.LastName + "%"));
        }

        var results = claims.OrderByDescending(m => m.MatterNumber).ToListAsync();

        return results;
    }
```

Here is my Claims entity:

```
public class Claim
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClaimNumber { get; set; }
    public string MatterNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Data { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string[] Errors { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<string>  SearchResults { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime EditedDate { get; set; }
    public string EditedBy { get; set; }  
}
```

Here are the errors

[image]

Comment: Please review [MCVE] guidance and [edit] code accordingly. In particular definition of `Claims` property used in `var claims = await _context.Claims` is missing making it hard to figure out why you expect that to work.

Comment: Hi Alexei. What else can I do to make my post more understandable?

Comment: Neither your C# compiler nor me can understand the `var claims = await _context.Claims;` line. The compiler at least has some idea is it sees the type of `_context.Claims`... no one on SO knows the type. It's very unusual to store tasks (or other awaitables) in property called "Claims" but who knows...

Comment: "Claims" is not a property, it's an Entity!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_context.Claims` is not async therefore you do not need to await it.

`.ToListAsync()` is async therefore you do need to await it.

Try this instead.

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Claim>> GetClaims(GetClaimsDto claimParams)
    {
        var claims = _context.Claims;

        if (claimParams.MatterNumber != null) {
            claims = claims.Where(c => c.MatterNumber == claimParams.MatterNumber);
        }

        if (claimParams.FirstName != String.Empty) {
            claims = claims.Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.FirstName, "%" + claimParams.FirstName + "%"));
        }

        if (claimParams.LastName != String.Empty) {
            claims = claims.Where(c => EF.Functions.Like(c.LastName, "%" + claimParams.LastName + "%"));
        }

        var results = await claims.OrderByDescending(m => m.MatterNumber).ToListAsync();

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: oh I see now! Thanks! FYI - I had to add one little part to make it work. var claims = _context.Claims.Select(c => c);